# How to send SSO claims to a Sitefinity based site from a non-Sitefinity application?

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, sitefinity

Please help.

How can I send claims to a Sitefinity based site from a non-Sitefinity application.

I have Sitefinity site user login/password and Membership provider name.

As a result I need Sitefinity site opened in the browser with my user already logged in.

Comment: Have you managed to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a token with the following method :

```
    private string CreateToken(string name)
                {

                    var key = this.HexToByte("... here is the same hexadecimal code that is specified in SecurityConfug.config file in securityTokenIssuers tag ... ");

                    var sb = new StringBuilder();

// here I'm adding info from claims, only these two claims are needed
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}&", UrlEncode(ClaimTypes.Name), name);
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}&", UrlEncode("http://schemas.sitefinity.com/ws/2011/06/identity/claims/domain"), "Default");

                    sb
                        .AppendFormat("TokenId={0}&", UrlEncode(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()))
                        .AppendFormat("Issuer={0}&", UrlEncode("http://localhost"))
                        .AppendFormat("Audience={0}&", UrlEncode("http://localhost"))
                        .AppendFormat("ExpiresOn={0:0}", (DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1) - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalSeconds );

                    var unsignedToken = sb.ToString();

                    var hmac = new HMACSHA256(key);
                    var sig = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(unsignedToken));

                    string signedToken = String.Format("{0}&HMACSHA256={1}",
                        unsignedToken,
                        UrlEncode(Convert.ToBase64String(sig)));

                    return signedToken;    

                }

    private byte[] HexToByte(string hexString)
            {
                byte[] returnBytes = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
                for (int i = 0; i < returnBytes.Length; i++)
                    returnBytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
                return returnBytes;
            }
```

And then I'm sending my token either via GET or via POST method as a parameter named **wrap_access_token**. If I use GET method, I encode the token using the method below. If I use POST method, then I do not need to encode it additionally.

```
var token = CreateToken(login);
var wrapped_token = UrlEncode(token);
Response.Redirect(baseUrl + "/?wrap_access_token=" + wrapped_token);


    private string UrlEncode(string input)
    {
        var encodedInput = WebUtility.UrlEncode(input);
        encodedInput = Regex.Replace(encodedInput, "(%[0-9A-F]{2})", c => c.Value.ToLowerInvariant());
        return encodedInput;
    }
```

Comment: I am confused a little. Especially by this "var key = this.HexToByte("... here is the same hexadecimal code that is specified in SecurityConfug.config file in securityTokenIssuers tag ... ");". Like what do I put in the parentheses here? Where does this function live? I have a mobile ionic app that needs to launch a link to my Sitefinity site and auto log the user in. They are logged in via Sitefinity creds on my mobile app already via JWT tokens and custom WCF REST service we implemented on Sitefinity site.